# Make an image link cover the whole image, after scaling in CSS?

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
                <div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(Images/Image\ 1.jpg)"></div>

                <div class="img-text-wrapper">
                    <div class="logo-wrapper">
                        <a href="about.html">
                            <img src="Images/Logos/Logo 1.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="subtitle">
                        <a href="about.html">
                            Lab Reports
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.portfolio-img-background {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
.portfolio-img-background {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img-text-wrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
.logo-wrapper img{
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition: 1s;
    font-weight: 600;
    transform: scale(1);

}
.img-text-wrapper:hover .logo-wrapper img{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: lightseagreen;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.img-text-wrapper .subtitle{
    transition: 1s;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: transparent;
}
.img-text-wrapper:hover .subtitle{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: lightseagreen;
}

.img-darken {
    transition: 1s;
    filter: brightness(10%);
}
```

Hi, I want to make Image 1 a link so that I when I click on any part of it, it directs to a new page. I've made it work for logo 1 and subtitle 1, but I'm unsure how to do the same thing for the image I have in style? Is the only way to do this to take out of div? because it's easier with the formatting if I keep it in there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside of a link

```
<a href="http://www.myredirect.com/mynewpage">
    <img src="Images/Logos/Logo 1.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: I've tried something like that. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Your advice worked thank you. I made it work for the logo and subtitle. But I can't make it work for image 1 which is inside div. Any advice on how to do this? I've put my new code above

Comment: Does putting that inside of an `<a href='...'> </a>` not work?